# Add a DIV that takes up all available vertical space

Tags: css, html

I have an empty page with one DIV on it:

```
<div style="height: 20%;
            min-height: 10px;
            max-height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: blue;"></div>
```

I want to add a DIV after this one that takes up all remaining vertical space on the page.  How do I do it?

I've spent all day on this and CSS is starting to drive me crazy.

Comment: Lol - I tried using tables too, but it didn't work.. mind telling me how'd I'd do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has to be inside this div?

If it's a just a color filler, just put your blue div in a another div wich you give a background color and make that one fit 100% of your browser window?

It will look like 2 divs beneath eachother. If you need content you can always just put another div under your blue one with whatever content you want.

EDIT:
code example:
http://jsbin.com/efefe/2

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The background-colors are just there so you can see the DIVS.  What I have is an application where I have a Google Map, and beneath it an elevation profile.  So I generally want the map to occupy 80% of the screen (it needs as much screen as possible), and the elevation profile to have 20%.  However, as the vertical size of the screen shrinks, the elevation profile must stay visible (min-height), and if someone has a large screen, I don't want the elevation profile to waste space that is better suited for the map (max-height).

Comment: And the way Google Maps works, must have a container div with a height or it shrinks to zero.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK IF THE CONTENTS IN THE 2ND DIV NEED TO SCROLL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two divs:

```
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'></div>
```

where #one has variable height and #two should consume all remaining vertical space you can do:

```
/* Note you could add a container div instead of using the body */
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#one {
  flex: none;
}
#two {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Furthermore, if you want #two to be scrollable you can add:

```
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

which will allow it to scroll vertically to show it's whole contents.

You can read more about display:flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).