# How to create a div filling the vertical available space without overlapping the containing div?

Tags: css, layout, html, cross-browser

I'm working on a layout with a container (div), inside the container there are two elements, a div for the header and another div for the content.
The header div has a fixed height, the div for the content must fill the available space.
The container div has own style and cannot be overlapped.
My goal is to create simple div based elements to dispose simple widgets on a web page.

I checked the other similar questions like:

- [How to make a div expand to fit available vertical space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351674/how-to-make-a-div-expand-to-fit-available-vertical-space)
- [Force  to fill all available vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884085/force-div-to-fill-all-available-vertical-space)
- [Add a DIV that takes up all available vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432288/add-a-div-that-takes-up-all-available-vertical-space)

But none of this solutions applies to me.

I managed to get this html/css:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .workbench {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: white;
            }
            .widget {
                width: 100px;
                height: 500px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 50px;
                border: solid 1px black;
                margin: 2px;
            }
            .widget-header {
                height: 50px;
                border: solid 1px red;
                margin: 2px;
            }
            .widget-body {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                border: solid 1px blue;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="workbench" class="workbench">
            <div id="widget" class="widget">
                <div id="widget-header" class="widget-header">
                    Header
                </div>
                <div id="widget-body" class="widget-body">
                    Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is working like a charm on FireFox and Chrome, but doesn't work on Internet Explorer 8:

[image: Page result]

Can you help me?

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you testing on?

Comment: made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xnxN/2/) out of this and rendered on practically all IE releases, and the problem only seem to reproduce on versions 6 and 5.5. **do you really wanna go there?**

Comment: Using fiddle the IE8 shows the compatibility view button and the render is correct, loading the html from a local file the result is like the screenshot in the question, do you know why IE8 renders different between fiddle and a local file?

Comment: @EliranMalka thanks a lot for using fiddle, I can tell the difference between the fiddle html and mine, I was using xml header, while IE8 for correct rendering need the <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

realizing you're not aiming at the IE5.5 / IE6 market, and by your descriptions (renders fine on jsFiddle, while not from a file), the issue seem to originate from the absence of a [doctype declaration](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

in order for the document to render correctly you must specify a doctype, to deny the browser from falling to quirksmode. your document seem to conform to a valid XHTML convention, therefore you can use the XHTML transitional doctype to instruct IE8 to render in standards mode, or use the HTML5 doctype (along with an [HTML5 shim/shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/), if you'll be using HTML5's semantics as well).

just for convenience, the XHTML transitional doctype declaration:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

*note: [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) contains an HTML5 shiv of its own, and is recommended regardless to ease up the development.*

*here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xnxN/2/) for you to mess around with*

Comment: Yes the doctype was the problem, thanks a lot for the useful info! I'll check the shiv

Answer (score -1):

As you have a height on the widget of 500px and the widget header is 50px; why not just make the widget-body 450px; (also subtracting any additional margin and padding) and make the whidget-header and widget-body relative positioning.

Comment: Yes, in the example the widget height is fixed, but in the real use I have different widgets of different height, I need a solution to work on any of them without fixing the widget-body height each time

Answer (score -2):

jquery can help with this.

```
$('.workbench').each(function(){
  var total=$(this).height();
  var headerHeight=$(this).find('.widget-header').height();
  $(this).find('.widget-body').height(total-headerHeight);
});
```

Comment: **[jQuery is not the answer to everything.](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)**

Comment: @Eliran: useless comment. didn't get the purpose of your link. i said jquery can help. if you can prove that it cannot. ptove it. dont make trivial statments. but when building widgets, jquery is absolutely a very valid choice to help with such cases.

Comment: jQuery can obviously help, but the OP didn't mention using it, and including an external library for an Ad-Hoc solution seems redundant. it's always best to **[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)** :)